# Blob Filtering in AForge.Net

Tags: c#, .net, image, aforge

As you know when we use BlobFiltering class in AForge.Net, it uses the black color (exactly RGB(0,0,0)) for the background color and remove blobs.

Is it possible to change the background color?

UPDATE :
for example for this image this Filtering not worked (i want to remove little areas)

[image]

and my desired result is :

[image]

Comment: Can you post/link to a sample colourful image that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @JMK For example, when you have an Image with PNG format and has some transparent pixel, this filter doesn't work!

Comment: Could you post an actual example that we could work with though?

Comment: Interesting image, what do you want the end result to be?

Comment: Are you always looking for the bottom right-hand corner of the image, or is it the portion of the image with the most substance?

Comment: No, in this image the bottom right-hand corner is the goal, it's randomly.

Answer (score 0):

hmm it seams the noise is blak and white only ?.
just scan for pixels if a row or column has only those colors shrink your down squaring.

Answer (score 0):

At the first time you must remove noise.
for removing noise use aforge library and Median(5).
It remove the noise. and you can find the big area.

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/af40e7dd-59d2-aa3f-b694-995a076a8c61.htm